# Security Review: Lightning: CSS Outside Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, security, security-review

In our SF Security Re-Review report a lightning component was flagged for "Lightning: CSS Outside Component".

The lines they referenced were:

```
...
<button style="font-size: 20px;top: 0.5rem;right: 0.5rem;color : black;"
        class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse"
        title="Close" onclick="{!c.closeMetrixModel}">X</button>
...
```

```
...
<div class="slds-form-element " style="margin-top:20px;">
...
```

We passed the initial security review and I am positive that we had inline styles back then. That was a couple years ago though.

I was under the impression that the issue to avoid is to not modify styles of DOM elements that don't belong to your component and don't use non-standard positioning.

When did this change to inline styles being disallowed completely?

Answer (score 5):

This is a normal part of the content security policy that Salesforce requires. Over the years this has become stricter (as online security tends to do). [Mozilla's MDN web documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/style-src#violation_cases) on Content Security Policy also considers this a requirement. In that sense there's nothing left to do but place the inline CSS in an CSS file.

The reason for this is explained in this Google Web Fundamentals post on the  [Content Security Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp#inline_code_is_considered_harmful):

> It should be clear that CSP is based on allowlist origins, as that's
> an unambiguous way of instructing the browser to treat specific sets
> of resources as acceptable and to reject the rest. Origin-based
> allowlists don't, however, solve the biggest threat posed by XSS
> attacks: inline script injection. If an attacker can inject a script
> tag that directly contains some malicious payload
> (sendMyDataToEvilDotCom();), the browser has no
> mechanism by which to distinguish it from a legitimate inline script
> tag. CSP solves this problem by banning inline script entirely: it's
> the only way to be sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I was reviewing the CSP for lightning components I saw that SF says "Inline JavaScript is not blocked by the CSP but is blocked in the security review ". I didn't think that was CSS but the documentation you provided makes it seem that way.