# Managed Package Security Review - Dynamic Inline CSS

Tags: managed-package, isv

According to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/350705/security-review-lightning-css-outside-component) thread inline CSS is not allowed to prevent an attacker from injecting a script. However does anybody know what is Salesforce's stance on adding inline CSS after the component has finished loading.

**Example**

```
handleAnEvent(evt) {
    this.myElement.style.top = '122' + px;
}
```

Comment: I think it will be flagged. What won't be is adding or changing the classes associated with an element.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW. I am aware about the changing of the classes. Unfortunately not all styling can be predicted for the use of classes. Thanks for the response though, I am going to take a different approach.